# Laravel custom Facades class not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following dir in my laravel-4 application:

**app/Latheesan**

This has been added to my `composer.json` like this:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "psr-0": {
        "Latheesan": "app/"
    }
    ...
},
```

Given that set-up, I want to create a custom Facade class called *Helpers* so that I can use it for various operations in my app, for e.g. `Helpers::getFreeStock();`

To achieve this, I have created the following folders & files:

[image]

with the following codes in the respective files:

**app/Latheesan/System/Helpers/Facades/Helpers.php**

```
<?php namespace Latheesan\System\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Helpers extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'helpers'; }

}
```

**app/Latheesan/System/Helpers/Helpers.php**

```
<?php namespace Latheesan\System\Helpers;

class Helpers {

    /**
     * Get free stock levels by organisation id.
     * If param $skus is empty, free stock will be calculated for every inventory organisation owns.
     *
     * @param $organisation_id
     * @param array $skus
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFreeStock($organisation_id, $skus = [])
    {
        return 'hello world - todo actual implementation';
    }

}
```

**app/Latheesan/System/Helpers/HelpersServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace Latheesan\System\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelpersServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['helpers'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new Helpers;
        });
    }

}
```

Now I have updated the *app/config/app.php* like so:

```
// Add service provider
'Latheesan\System\Helpers\HelpersServiceProvider'

...

// Create alias
'Helpers' => 'Latheesan\System\Helpers\Facades\Helpers'
```

Finally, to test this, I created the following route:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    dd(Helpers::getFreeStock(1, ['vcf001']));
});
```

When I visit this `/test` to test the helpers Facade class, I get the following error:

## Class 'Latheesan\System\Helpers\Facades\Helpers' not found

What have I done wrong here? Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Your facade file has namespace `Latheesan\System\Helpers` which is missing `Facades`

Comment: Thanks, now i am getting a different error: `Cannot redeclare class Latheesan\System\Helpers\Facades\Helpers`

Comment: Ignore my previous remark. After making the change, I had to run `composer dump-auto` and it fixed the problem. All working great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please answer your question maybe other users are helped with it.

Comment: @Luceos Okay, I have now posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Luceos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717181/luceos), I have fixed the problem. I had a typo in the namespace in *app/Latheesan/System/Helpers/Facades/Helpers.php* file.

The correct code should be like this:

```
<?php namespace Latheesan\System\Helpers\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Helpers extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'helpers'; }

}
```

After changing that, I had to run **composer dump-auto** and everything worked great.